# Issues getting something to show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have a section I am wanting to be hidden on page load and only show if a tab is selected or if a person is coming from a link.

I have figured out what is causing my issue. It is that I am showing the section - `service-display-box` when someone comes from the link.

```
//Showing Service Section from Link
    $(function(){

        //get the section name from hash
        var sectionName = window.location.hash.slice(1);

        //then show the section
         $('#service-display-box').show();
         $(window.location.hash).show().scroll().siblings().hide();
    })
```

I thought of a way to get the page to load without showing the section, but now the section does not appear when coming from a link.

This is what I did:

```
//Showing Service Section from Link
$(function(){

    //get the section name from hash
    var sectionName = window.location.hash.slice(1);

    if (sectionName > 1) { //added
    //then show the section
     $('#service-display-box').show();
     $(window.location.hash).show().scroll().siblings().hide();
    } else { //added
        $('#service-display-box').hide(); //added
    } //added
})
```

How do I make this show only if someone comes from a link instead of on normal page load?

Click on any of the links and when you get to the new page you will see that the `service-display-box` does not display what-so-ever (this is due to my updated code from above - with the if statement). I am wanting to show the section when coming from the specific links otherwise I want the section to remain hidden unless one of the tabs is selected.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
<div id="service-display-box">
      <div id="service-display-box-container">
        <div class="service-item-box" id="service1">
          <div class="service-item-title">DEMOLITION</div>
        </div>
        <div class="service-item-box" id="service2">
          <div class="service-item-title">ENVIRONMENTAL SOLUTIONS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="service-item-box" id="service3">
          <div class="service-item-title">CONCRETE CRUSHING</div>
        </div>
        <div class="service-item-box" id="service4">
          <div class="service-item-title">ASSET RECOVERY</div>
        </div>
        <div class="service-item-box" id="service5">
          <div class="service-item-title">SCRAP METAL RECYCLING</div>
        </div>
        <div class="service-item-box" id="service6">
          <div class="service-item-title">FOUNDATION REMOVAL</div>
        </div>
        <div id="service-top">Back to all services</div>
      </div>
    </div>


#service-display-box {
  margin: 50px 0;
  display: none;
}

//For tabs to stay active
$('.service-tab-block').click(function() {
    $('.service-tab-block').css({"background":"purple" , "color" : "#000"});
    $(this).css({"background":"#000", "color":"#FFF"});

    //To get the service display box to show
    var item_number = $(this).attr('id').replace('service_tab', '');
    $('#service-display-box').show();
     $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#service-display-box").offset().top
  }, 1500);
    $('#service'+item_number).show().siblings().hide();
    $('#service-top').show();
});

//To go back up to Service options
$("#service-top").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#service-tabs").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});

//Showing Service Section from Link
$(function(){

    //get the section name from hash
    var sectionName = window.location.hash.slice(1);

    //then show the section
     $('#service-display-box').show();
     $(window.location.hash).show().scroll().siblings().hide();
})
```